# How do I determine the actual values of certain Objective-C constants?

Tags: objective-c, rust, core-graphics, ffi

I'm using Objective-C functions in my Rust application through the layer of different bindings. So far it was simple to call Objective-C functions and to implement the required functionality without any problems. But now it seems that I found an impediment which I don't know how to solve, some of the functions from `CoreGraphics` require several constants to work properly.

So the question is how can I get the actual value of a particular constant? For instance, let's say that I want to get the value of `CGRectInfinite` constant (CoreGraphics), is it possible to get it?

For integer constants/enums it was quite simple -- I just opened XCode and navigated to the appropriate header file, which contained the required values, then I just copy-pasted the values into my application.  But what to do if a constant is something like `CGRect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extern const` in C can be declared in Rust as a `static`.

```
extern {
    pub static CGRectInfinite: CGRect;
}
```

The use of `CGRectInfinite` is unsafe. You'd better provide a safe wrapper to access it.

```
impl CGRect {
    pub fn infinite() -> CGRect {
        unsafe { CGRectInfinite }
    }
}
```

The [actual value of `CGRectInfinite`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135341/why-is-there-a-difference-between-cgrectinfinite-and-a-cgrect-with-all-members-s), by the way, is:

```
#[cfg(target_pointer_width="64")]
pub const CGRectInfinite: CGRect = CGRect {
    origin: CGPoint {
        x: -0.5 * f64::MAX,
        y: -0.5 * f64::MAX,
    },
    size: CGSize {
        width: f64::MAX,
        height: f64::MAX,
    },
};

// similar on 32-bit, replacing f64 by f32.
```

but you should not rely on the actual value of the constant.